# Adicionar parâmetro em todas as minhas URLs internas

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tipo, meu site tem vários posts e tal, gostaria que todos os links do meu Próprio site ficasse com ?ref=app no final.. mesmo eu mudando de pagina ele ficasse com o parâmetro.

Existe um código ? uma forma de fazer isso ?

Comment: Pesquise isso relacionado a htaccess, pode ser que te ajude

Comment: Poderia ser mais objetivo na pergunta? Esclarecer alguns pontos de como está fazendo?

Comment: Tipo, meu site quero que abre dentro de um App, e quero que quando ele abra dentro de um app fique com todas as url dele com a ref=app, assim vou saber que e de pelo app e editar o tema como eu quiser so pro app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usa rum script para capturar sua URL e editar ela para a nova referencia.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // PROTETOR DE LINK
  (() => {
  const urlsBases = ["seusite.com", "localhost"];

  for (let urlBase of urlsBases) {

    const anchors = document.querySelectorAll("a[href*='" + urlBase + "']");

    anchors.forEach(el => {
        let urlProtegida = el.getAttribute("href") + "?ref=app"

        el.setAttribute("href", urlProtegida)

        console.log(urlProtegida)
    });
  }
  })();
  </script>
```

Ou seja, ele pegou seu domínio principal e adicionou a referencia: ?ref=app no final.

Comment: Muito bom!valeu cara.